# React Native still runs with incorrectly defined types (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to convert React Native project to TypeScript-based project.
So far, I converted `.jsx` files to `.tsx` files, and when I run `yarn tsc`, it throws tons of error.
However, my `npx react-native start` && `npx react-native run-android` still just runs without any complaining. (I tried cleaning cache)

I intentionally defined one of the variables to incorrect type and code still just runs fine. What I am doing wrong? Why does my project still work?

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does my project still work?

Most type errors do not actually prevent your typescript from emitting javascript code. Typescript is still capable of emitting code with type errors. All that really *needs* doing is removing types anotations, which lets the remaining pure javascript shine through.*

If you look at [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgZSgJwJZgOYC4bTZmAXhgEYAmAZiA) you will see this typescript code:

```
const aString: string = 123 // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

is being compiled into this javascript: (see the right hand pane, click ".JS")

```
"use strict";
const aString = 123;
```

It has type errors, *and* it emits runnable javascript code.

When you run a project compiled with type errors, you will most likely encounter runtime errors as a result. So you should definitely fix those type errors.

---

** And some other transpilation non type dependent syntax like `enum` , chainable null accessors `foo?.bar`, etc.*

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I thought these two lines  `"noEmit": true` and `"noEmitOnError": true,` would prevent compiling. I guess I am not understanding those correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup exactly, but `tsc` may not be what's compiling your code, so that option might be getting ignored. Tools like webpack, or babel, may just be stripping types and not actually doing typechecking. But if you have `noEmit: true` then `tsc` will never emit code, so the `noEmitOnError` setting wouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: If you want to see type-errors, add `"scripts":{ "build": "tsc", }` to your `package.json`. That should run tsc, picking up your tsconfig settings. See https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#adding-typescript-to-a-project Useful for Ci/Cd.